# Magit help popup enabled by default

Tags: magit, spacemacs

Every time I open Magit status buffer I need to press `?`. 
How can I make it so it opens automatically?

doing this didn't help

```
(add-hook 'magit-mode 'magit-dispatch-popup)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no hook variable named `magit-mode`. You were looking for `magit-mode-hook` (mode hooks are always named `MODENAME-hook`). That's not the solution here, though.

I can only imagine this very quickly going from "I have to press <kbd>?</kbd> every time to get the help" to "I have to press <kbd>q</kbd> every time to dismiss the help", however you can do what you've asked for by defining some after-advice for `magit-status`:

```el
(defadvice magit-status (after my-magit-status-dispatch-popup)
  (magit-dispatch-popup))
(ad-activate 'magit-status)
```

n.b. That won't trigger for anything *other* than calling `magit-status`, so refreshing the status buffer (which calls `magit-refresh`) won't do it (which I think is a good thing).

---

Edit: In more recent versions of Magit the above code causes a byte-compilation warning (see comments), but you could use the following variation instead:

```el
(defadvice magit-status (after my-magit-status-dispatch)
  (call-interactively 'magit-dispatch))
(ad-activate 'magit-status)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but issues a warning now: `Warning (bytecomp): ‘magit-dispatch-popup’ is an obsolete function (as of Magit 3.0.0); use ‘magit-dispatch’ instead.` - 
When I use `magit-dispatch`, it complains that is for interactive use only :/